# How can I list all of the configuration sources or properties in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to ensure that a particular configuration property is being read from a configuration source. I was going to print out all of the configuration sources (or print out all of the configuration properties), but I can’t seem to figure out how to do that.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get a list of all the keys discovered by all configuration sources by doing:

```
var keys = builder.Build().AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

I haven't found a way to build each configuration source separately so you could see the sources individually.

In debug mode, you can see the private members and peek into each configuration source:

[image: Debug configuration providers]

Comment: Thanks! However… “'IConfigurationRoot' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationRoot' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)”

Comment: Do you have `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` ?

Comment: I do indeed. Tried `using System.Data;` too…

Comment: Odd. `AsEnumerable` is an extension method in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 1.0.0-rc2-final`. Are you using the RC2 versions of the configuration packages?

Comment: No—everything `Microsoft.Extensions` that I have is `rc1-final`.

Comment: @BenKlein Ah, gotcha. Upgrade to RC2? :)

Comment: :D I suppose I’ll have to do that… unless there happened to be an RC 1 workaround…

Comment: @BenKlein Not that I'm aware of, sorry!

Answer (score 84):

From .NET Core 3.0+ you can cast your `IConfiguration` to a `IConfigurationRoot` and use the [GetDebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationrootextensions.getdebugview?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) extension method. That will generates a human-readable view of the configuration showing where each value came from. E.g.

```cs
var root = (IConfigurationRoot)Configuration;
var debugView = root.GetDebugView();
```

Sample output to `debugView`:

```
applicationName=Project.Name (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ChainedConfigurationProvider)
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=32774 (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
ASPNETCORE_LOGGING:
  CONSOLE:
    DISABLECOLORS=true (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80 (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1 (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
AllowedHosts=* (JsonConfigurationProvider for 'appsettings.json' (Required))
Kestrel:
  Certificates:
    Development:
      Password=xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx (JsonConfigurationProvider for 'secrets.json' (Optional))
EmailOptions:
  EnableSsl=False (JsonConfigurationProvider for 'appsettings.json' (Required))
ENVIRONMENT=Development (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ChainedConfigurationProvider)
HOME=/root (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
HOSTNAME=2cb0f5c24cc0 (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
HTTPS_PORT=32774 (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ChainedConfigurationProvider)
NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2 (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
PWD=/app (EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider)
RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ChainedConfigurationProvider)
URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80 (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ChainedConfigurationProvider)
USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1 (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ChainedConfigurationProvider)
```

Comment: I was hoping that `GetDebugView()` would return an structured/enumerable object-graph view of the configuration tree instead of a flat-string - fortunately `GetDebugView` is straightforward to reimplement.

Comment: @Dai agreed, feel free to share your re-implementation if you have it handy!

Comment: This works great. I will add only one thing here: If you have secrets in your config, it makes sense to not log these values, and it can be easily achieved here. For example, is you use KeyVault provider: `root.GetDebugView(x => x.ConfigurationProvider is AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider ? "*secret*" : x.Value ?? "<null>");`

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I have been faced a similar problem.
I found the solution to a task here:
https://github.com/Wallsmedia/DotNetCore.Configuration.Formatter

```
    public static List<string> AllConfigurationKeys(this IConfigurationRoot root)
    {
        (string Value, IConfigurationProvider Provider) GetValueAndProvider(
                                                            IConfigurationRoot root,
                                                            string key)
        {
            foreach (IConfigurationProvider provider in root.Providers.Reverse())
            {
                if (provider.TryGet(key, out string value))
                {
                    return (value, provider);
                }
            }

            return (null, null);
        }

        void RecurseChildren(
                HashSet<string> keys,
                IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> children, string rootPath)
        {
            foreach (IConfigurationSection child in children)
            {
                (string Value, IConfigurationProvider Provider) valueAndProvider = GetValueAndProvider(root, child.Path);

                if (valueAndProvider.Provider != null)
                {
                    keys.Add(rootPath + ":" + child.Key);
                }

                RecurseChildren(keys, child.GetChildren(), child.Path);
            }
        }

        var keys = new HashSet<string>();
        RecurseChildren(keys, root.GetChildren(), "");
        return keys.ToList();
    }
```